# tomcat error while running spring program

Tags: spring

i m running hello world program in spring which works fine with eclipse but when i run it in tomcat separately it shows me error

rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMapping' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'helloController' while setting bean property 'urlMap' with key [TypedStringValue: value [/hello.html], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [net.roseindia.web.HelloWorldController] for bean with name 'helloController' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.roseindia.web.HelloWorldController

Comment: where should i specify the classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like net.roseindia.web.HelloWorldController is not in your classpath.

Comment: where should i make entry in the class path

Comment: You needn't. Is the class in WEB-INF/classes/net/roseindia/web/?